# Google translate not translating the site correctly

Tags: magento, google-translate

I was testing Google translate on my website for some time, translating the site into various languages, Google seems to stop working correctly.

Occasionally the site will be translated to the language chosen previously.

Before I thought it was my browser cache, I cleared the cache several times but still the above problem occurs.

I was wondering if someone who might be experiencing the similar problems please help

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleared magento cache. Try clearing magento cache and disabling all magento cache

Admin >> System >> Cache Management

Comment: Disable the magento cache and check. This is like a cache issue so may be something related to cache